# How to make sure the systems inputs only the correct date format into sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a textbox which allows a user to enter a date for their date of birth. The application formats the date to "MM/dd/yyyy". The catch is if someones date of birth is 1/1/2000, l get an error as the date is not valid. How can l correct this so that if the user enters 1/1/2000 into the textbox, the application converts it to 01/01/2000 before insertion into sql server database.

```
      cn.Open();

      String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";//The format that the txt_dob control uses
      DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
      txtdob.Text, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO register ( DOB) VALUES(@DOB, cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtdob.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("saved")
      cn.Close();
```

Comment: Why aren't you storing the date as a date in the database?  You are adding the text, not the date object

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtdob.Text);` ??? What's the point of having `parsedDate` if you're not using it

Comment: Why don't you use a datepicker instead of a textbox for the user interface?   What do you want the program to do if the user inputs "Yesterday"?

Comment: For starters, [stop using addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @penleychan i tried it with cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", parsedDate); but l still get an error if i enter 1/1/2000 i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DateTime.ParseExact is failing because your custom format requires 2 digit month and 2 digit day. Change the custom format to single digit of each and do tryparseexact to only insert correctly formatted dates.

```
cn.Open();

  String dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy";
  DateTime parsedDate;

  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdob, dateFormat, 
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
  {
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO register ( DOB) VALUES(@DOB, cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", parsedDate);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("saved")
  }

cn.Close();
```

There are better ways to execute the sql command, but I'm just focusing on solving your question.

Comment: your answer is right if the datetime is always '1/1/2000' but this does not solve the OP problem on source. The code exposed will fail if the user inputs '01/01/2000'. The problem is that OP is not doing any validation on the textbox or not using a datetime picker.

Comment: @NicoRiff, M/d/yyyy works with single digit and double digit months/days. You can test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As others said you should store the date on a `datetime` column on your database. Then when you insert the date it should be automatically converted to the SQL type you are expecting:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = parsedDate;
```

Comment: l tried doing that, changed the date column to datetime and still didn't work. If i enter 1/1/2000 instead of 01/01/2000 l get an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: The problem is not on your database call but in yout ParseExact method... you chould catch the possible values